# Does socket support read-only operations

Tags: sockets

On the server,File A is opened by Word,then in client,I want to use Socket to get the size of File A ,and the problem is the server return "550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. \r".
Is there a way to modify the Socket,so that I can get the file size,though the file is opened on the server.Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What you describe implies the client is sending a request to a server, and the server is accessing the file. If so, there is nothing that can be done on the client side. But on the server side, how exactly is it opening the file to get its size? Can you show that code? Perhaps it is simply requesting too many permissions that Word is blocking. We don't know, we can't see what it is doing. As an alternative, it does not need to open the file just to get its size, it can get that info from the filesystem's metadata instead, such as with `FindFirstFile()` or `GetFileAttributesEx()`.

Comment: I asked for the *server's* code, not the *client's*. As I said, there is nothing you can do about this issue on the client side. On the server side, if it insists on opening the file to get its size, make sure it is opening the file with bare minimum rights (probably `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` will suffice), and hope that Word allows those rights while it has the file open. If not, you need to forget opening the file at all, like I mentioned earlier.